# NSSecureCoding VS saving id

Tags: objective-c, nssecurecoding

i am on objective-c, macOS.

I am currently rewriting an application to support NSSecureCoding Protocol.
In some classes i have some properties like this

```
@property id objectValue;
```

These objects can be of very dynamic kind (NSString, custom object ...)
On loading i did this before:

```
_objectValue = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"objectValue"];
```

With NSSecureCoding i need to specify the class which i cannot do with id obviously.
So here are my questions:

1. Is it OK to pass a superclass like NSObject even if it's basically an NSString?

   ```
   _objectValue = [coder decodeObjectOfClass:[NSObject class] forKey:@"objectValue"];
   ```

   But... doesn't this counteract the idea of NSSecureCoding?
2. Is there another (better) approach?

Edit:
Just seen that this is possible with multiple classes decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey: - would the correct approach be to list all classes possible?

Comment: Per your edit, the answer is yes - you just list all potential classes that could be unarchived from the archive.

Comment: Is there another approach? Well, not ideal, but if you can wrap all your classes into a property list and use ```NSPropertyListSerialization``` you sidestep a lot of the issues and later when your classes change it might be easier to handle. You can e.g. add a ```version``` when you serialise to a property list and then it is really easy later on when you deserialise to support older versions.